# Remove a part of url with rewrite

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm not familiarized with this feature and I've found some examples how to do something but I don't know how to set this case:

I want this url `http://www.domain.co.uk/anything/en` to become `http://www.domain.co.uk/anything/`

I want to remove the final 'en'

I've tried with:

```
^/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/en
/{R:1}/{R:2}
```

or

```
^http://www.domain.co.uk/([_0-9a-z-]+)/(en)
http://www.domain.co.uk/{R:1}/
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule:

```
<rule name="Remove en" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/en$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

It will match any url ending with `/en` and remove this part.
From your example, `http://www.domain.co.uk/anything/en` will be **rewritten** as `http://www.domain.co.uk/anything`

If you want the user to be **redirected**, then use the following rule:

```
<rule name="Remove en" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)/en$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The `type="Redirect"` with no option triggers a permanent(301) redirect.

Comment: Thanks cheesemacfly,
I follow your advice and this link http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module but i don't know why does not work...

Any idea?

Thanks again